# How do I add Update Manager to the Activities/Applications tab within GNOME Shell?

Tags: 11.10, gnome, update-manager

I've been playing with GNOME Shell, and I like it.  But there is one issue I'm having.  When I click on Activities, and select Applications, I scroll down and I notice that Update Manager (and others (like Synaptic)) are missing.

How do I add Update Manager (and others) to the Activities/Application within GNOME Shell?  I'm using Ubuntu 11.10 Oneiric.

Answer (score 1):

Try `alacarte`, install it using `sudo apt-get alacarte`.

[image]

It allows you to easily create links anywhere plus you can move/check the commands/edit the current links.